# Clifford Algebra: Expression for $\sum_b(\gamma_a^{\;b})_{\alpha\beta}(\gamma_b^{\;c})_{\rho\delta}$

Tags: clifford-algebras

Is there any simple expression for this in general $D$-dimensions?

$$\sum_b(\gamma_a^{\;b})_{\alpha\beta}(\gamma_b^{\;c})_{\rho\delta}$$

where $\gamma^a$ are the usual $D$-dimensional gamma matrices and $\gamma^{ab}= \frac{1}{2}[\gamma^a,\gamma^b]$. The others are defined by Clifford algebra.

I have searched for lots of identities from Clifford Algebra like Fierz identities but they don't seem to be helpful.

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by ${\gamma_a}^b$? The product of $\gamma_a$ and $\gamma^b$, with $\gamma_a$ defined by lowering through the metric?

Comment: Yes, lowered by the euclidean metric.